# Константы в коде

Tags: java

Здравствуйте знаю что вопрос такой не соответствует тематике RUSO но тем не менее хочу спросить что лучше в коде хранить цифры либо константы?

к примеру лучше так:

```
  case APP_ZTIP_VALUE_REC:
```

или

```
 case "REC":
```

Comment: Всегда лучше константы, т.к это позволяет дать странной строке в кавычках, окоторой вы завтра забудете, осмысленное имя. И usage по коду можно искать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете ее в одном месте, то проще использовать второй вариант `case "REC"`. Константу лучше создавать тогда, когда ее значение нужно в нескольких местах или в принципе часто используется.

Например если частенько в классах задают константы `public static final` в случае, если их надо передавать в метод класса как параметр. И вместо прописывания стринги вручную, ты пишешь `SomeClass.APP_ZTIP_VALUE_REC`. Это позволит тебе быстро находить нужную константу и исключить риск ошибки в стринге.